# Is There a Tool That Can Be Used to Simulate Patch Deployment Scenarios Using WSUS?

Tags: windows-update, wsus

Can anyone suggest a tool/method to simulate various scenarios when using WSUS?  Or am I asking the impossible?  I'm curious to know if I deploy X number of patches over slow links is there any way of determining when all of the machines on the other end of the wire will be updated?

Answer (score 2):

Virtual machines in a test environment that allows you to implement rate-limiting (to simulate various link speeds) is the best solution. But, as Andrew noted, there are considerable costs associated with this.

Another approach might be to simply break out your pencil and perform some back-of-the-napkin calculations. What's the link speed, how large is the set of patches, can they be multicast, how many machines on the remote end, and so on. Once you've considered these variables you might decide that it's simpler to deliver a single set of patches to a second WSUS server on the far end and move on with life.

Not knowing anything about how your network is engineered makes this a difficult question to answer concisely.

Comment: Thank you, I suspect a "napkin" design plan will be where I go.  The number of clients out on the other end are few enough (90, 40, and 60 at three remote sites) for me not to have too much concern.  I'm just looking to validate what I know from experience in similar environments.

Comment: You should add that info to your original post. Deploying a WSUS server at each site with 30 or more systems should be a standard policy. Anytime your site becomes large enough that the SA staff cannot patch all systems in a day, you should be using a patch management server.

Comment: "Deploying a WSUS server at each site with 30 or more systems should be a standard policy" based on what?  Is there a "suggested/recommended" clients per WSUS?

Comment: That's my own thought. I don't remember seeing a standard number of clients per WSUS ... his main concern is bandwidth, and the time needed to transfer patches over slow links ...

Comment: A more concise way of putting what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about bandwidth and remote WSUS servers isn't an option, then you can also tune your BITS settings in a GPO for those sites; the clients may get the patches slower but better than not at all.

Answer (score -2):

Why have Virtual Machines become the knee-jerk reaction to administration problems?

VMs are not magic pixie dust to sprinkle over your problems.

You should figure out how long it takes to download a certain sized
file over the link. Nice round numbers are convenient, let's make it
1GB.

1. Time how long the upload/download takes (N)
2. Time how long 2 upload/downloads take (N+1)

Make a guess.

In this case your deployment of WSUS is interesting, usually WSUS is
deployed on the local end of a slow link. There are really only two
reasons to deploy WSUS: management and bandwidth. Putting WSUS on the
distant end of a link is really no different (bandwidth wise) from
downloading all your patches from Microsoft. Every client has to
access the same slow link.

Have you considered deploying another WSUS server at the local end of
your link?

If this is a branch office, and you do not want/cannot deploy a WSUS
server. Consider doing patches starting Friday evening and letting
them roll throughout the weekend.

Comment: The "plan" calls for WSUS servers at each of six locations.  I think that's overkill for the number clients supported.  My thought is one WSUS for the lot, I'm certain the local sites will update with no issue.  I just don't see that deploying a WSUS server for the small number of users, the satellite sites, is efficient.

Comment: I only read three sites in his comment. Is it too much to ask that each office has a domain controller and a WSUS? You can centralize email and some file servers, but logins and patch management should always be available. Have you had good results with a single WSUS, over slow links?

Comment: Because virtual machines are great simulation tools, they are cheap (no need to get ESX crazy to run a simulation there are plenty of free VMs to do the job), and easy to use. so usually when somebody talk about simulating something Virtual Machines come in at the top of the list.

Comment: Well, it's hard to find a 'free VM' with XP or Vista installed. Every installation is an activation. I just assume, in all my answers, OP doesn't have VLKs.

Comment: "VMs are not magic pixie dust to sprinkle over your problems."

Nice invective. I didn't answer the question naively, this seemed like an appropriate response to this problem. The OP mentioned "simulate", now unless we get into some truly interesting programming to simlulate some windows machines and patchy networks, why not use the standard solution, a virtual one?

Comment: Your answer just states- Virtual Machines. Which could be taken a number of ways. Your comment (to your post) clarifies it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for all of the excellent input.  I'll be going back with some of this info to get some more detailed answers (the due diligence on this one has been a bit lacking).